# moment.utc(date).local() still gives utc time.

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs

I'm getting a timestamp from a database in the format of `2017-06-28 23:24:17.1-07` and I'm trying to convert it to local time using moment, but I'm still getting back UTC time.

Here's a simulated version I plugged into my console:

```
var now = new Date(); // Fri Jun 30 2017 15:45:30 GMT-0700 (PDT)

// simulate date received from server
var now_utc = new Date(now.getUTCFullYear(), now.getUTCMonth(), now.getUTCDate(),  now.getUTCHours(), now.getUTCMinutes(), now.getUTCSeconds()); // Fri Jun 30 2017 22:45:41 GMT-0700 (PDT);

var local = moment.utc(now_utc).local().format('LLL') // "June 30, 2017 10:45 PM"

^ should be ~3:45pm.
```

As you can see, the output of `local` is the same as the input of `now_utc`.

Comment: Did you specific a time zone parameter?

Answer (score 1):

> I'm getting a timestamp from a database in the format of `2017-06-28 23:24:17.1-07` and I'm trying to convert it to local time using moment...

That's a fairly unusual string format to get directly from a database, but if that is indeed the string you have, then:

```
// parse the input string
var m = moment("2017-06-28 23:24:17.1-07", "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SZ");

// format the output string
var s = m.format("LLL");
```

There's no need to use the `Date` object at all, and there's no need to call `.local()` because local-mode is the default and you're providing an offset.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Using moment-timezone solved my problem, although I fail to understand why .local() didn't work.

Try modifying your local variable as follows:

var local = moment.utc(now_utc).tz(time-zone).format('LLL')

You can find your required time-zone value [here](https://momentjs.com/timezone/)

P.S. Don't forget to install the moment-timezone package.